# Scrobble to last.fm with iTunes home sharing

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipod, music, home-sharing

Is there a way to scrobble to last.fm what I play from my iPhone with home sharing?

**Edit:** last.fm currently scrobbles when I play right from my iTunes. I am using the last.fm mac app. When I stream music from my iTunes library on my mac with my iPhone, using home sharing, last.fm does not scrobble.

Comment: Do you have last.fm scrobbling for locally played tracks already working? Tracks played through Home Sharing show up in your "Most recently played" list as well and should get picked up automatically. If this doesn't work for you, please add some details about your setup and software.

Comment: I just edited my original question.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, using the following steps:

1. In iTunes, go to Preferences > Sharing Preferences. There is an option there called 'Home sharing computers and devices update play counts'. Turn that on.
2. After you've listened to some music, open the last.fm Scrobbler application on your computer, and it should prompt you to scrobble what you've just listened to.

Works for me - I'm using iTunes 11 on a Mac.